# how to use /dev/null for bash command

Tags: linux, bash, su

I am using below command to get result for my SQL query.

```
su - postgres -c 'psql -d dbname' with stdin "COPY ( my SQL query ) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER"
```

This works fine on my server but on different machine it is printing bash warning with output of SQL query.

For example -

```
/etc/profile: line 46: HISTSIZE: readonly variable
/etc/profile: line 50: HISTCONTROL: readonly variable
/etc/profile.d/20-tmout.sh: line 1: TMOUT: readonly variable
/etc/profile.d/history.sh: line 6: hcmnt_tty: readonly variable
name
abc
```

Please let me know anyway so that I can skip above warning messages and only get data.

If I would like to use /dev/null in this case how to modify above command to get data only.

Answer (score 0):

if what you mean is *"how to discard only error output?"*, the way to go is to redirect the standard error stream to oblivion (`/dev/null`), like so:

```sh
your-command 2>/dev/null
```

that way, if the command outputs data to standard out, it passes through, but any output to the standard error socket is discarded, so you won't see these error messages.

by the way, `2` here is a shorthand file descriptor for the standard error.

Comment: I don't think sweeping data under the rug is the desired effect here

Comment: @EliranMalka - I mentioned 2>/dev/null after my command it won't show stderr related to SQL command using psql. or is there anyway I can skip warnings from su - postgres related to /etc/profile.

Comment: i don't know such way, maybe some psql/postgres expert will share her knowledge..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is untested, but I hit this same error, your db session isn't read/write.  You can echo the statements to psql to force a proper session as follows.  I'm unsure as to how stdin may be effected

```
echo 'SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE; SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ WRITE ; COPY ( my SQL query ) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER' | su - postgres -c 'psql -d dbname' with stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

caution - bash hack

```
su - postgres -c 'psql -d dbname' with stdin "COPY ( my SQL query ) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER" | grep -v "readonly"
```